# What does the phrase "invariant under f" mean?

Tags: chaos-theory

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $f(x,y)=(\frac{x}{3}+11y^2,-2y)$.

Let $A=\{(3y^2,y)|y\in \mathbb{R}\}$.

Show that $A$ is invariant under $f$.

What is it asking?

Comment: It means the set does not change under f!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See that

$f(3y^2,y)=(\frac{3y^2}{3}+11y^2,-2y)=(12y^2,-2y)=(3(-2y)^2,(-2y))$

which is obiviously in the set A.

Comment: in $A$ because if we put $Y=-2y$ then $f(3y^2,y)=(3Y^2,Y)$ has the general element's of $A$ form.

Comment: @Mohamed. Yes I fixed that. Thanks. We can let Y=-2y in my answer.

Comment: Thanks  smanoos. My comment was for help more the questionner. Your answer is complete.